# Можно использовать TableView для разных ViewController и других объектов?

Tags: swift

Возникает вопрос можно ли использовать список (tableViewController) например для разных ячеек разные ViewController'ы не создавая типы ячеек например, если они все одинаковые например для 1 идет один контроллер для второй другой, для третей третий и т.д. или как подругому использовать множество элементов к множеству контроллеров?

это нужно для примера использования разных элементов в системе, а для них нужны разные контроллеры

Comment: только мне ничего не понятно?

Comment: есть контроллер, в  нем список, мне нужно, чтобы каждая ячейка отвечала за свой контроллер в сториборде такое воозможно вообще как то зделать или там все привязано segue или нужно делать отдельную ячейку для каждого контроллера. вот фото http://radikal.ru/lfp/s019.radikal.ru/i624/1609/63/ce051750af54.png/htm

Comment: то есть нажатие на ячейку tableview должно открывать соответствующий viewController?

Comment: в двух словах, если у тебя грубо говоря три вьюхи на которые надо перейти, то с делай с TableVIewController seque (переходы) на эти три экрана. И каждому seque дай разные identifier. Потом в методе didSelectRowAtIndexPath, отслеживай ячейку которая тебе нужна и задавай ей переход по identifier.

Comment: Ок попробую это дело

Comment: Вообщем я пытаюсь, если с одной tableViewCell тянут первый раз он выводит segue, а на вторую вьюху он просто перенаправляет первую на вторую